# WebDriverException : unhandled inspector error with code "-3200"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

i'm currently working on an app (python/django/redis) to track and register movement of grains on a farm.

My main app is working fine, i'm now trying to have my last page working.

The goal of the page is for the user to load it on his samsung tab while in reach of a network, then go in the field to gather some data that get register in the localStorage.

Once he is finished he goes back in reach of the network and press the loading button. When the button is pressed it send a post request, telling the view it need to gather the data from the localStorage and put it in a Redis key.

Here is the code of the view :

```
def creationField(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
        url='XXX.X.X.XX:XXXX/XXXXXXX/XXXXXXX'
        driver.get(url)
        storage = LocalStorage(driver)

        for i in range(1,50) :
            keyCubage = 'Wagon_'+ str(i) + '_cubageWagon'
            keyLimite = 'Wagon_'+ str(i) + '_limiteWagon'
            keyCiterne = 'Wagon_'+ str(i) + '_numCiterne'
            keyPBM = 'Wagon_'+ str(i) + '_pbmWagon'
            keyTar = 'Wagon_'+ str(i) + '_tarWagon'

            cubageWagon = storage.get(keyCubage)
            limiteWagon = storage.get(keyLimite)
            numCiterne = storage.get(keyCiterne)
            pbmWagon = storage.get(keyPBM)
            tarWagon = storage.get(keyTar)

            if (cubageWagon == None or limiteWagon == None or numCiterne == None or pbmWagon == None or tarWagon == None):
                result = "Break"
                break
            else:
                result = "REDIS WORK"
                r = redis.StrictRedis(host=settings.REDIS_AD, port=settings.REDIS_PORT, db='14')
                key = 'Wagon_' + str(i)
                r.hmset(key, {'Cubage': cubageWagon, 'limite': limiteWagon, 'numCiterne': numCiterne, 'pbmWagon': pbmWagon, 'tarWagon': tarWagon})
    return render(request, 'creationField.html', locals())
```

LocalStorage class :

```
class LocalStorage:

    def __init__(self, driver) :
        self.driver = driver

    def __len__(self):
        return self.driver.execute_script("return window.localStorage.length;")

    def items(self) :
        return self.driver.execute_script( \
            "var ls = window.localStorage, items = {}; " \
            "for (var i = 0, k; i < ls.length; ++i) " \
            "  items[k = ls.key(i)] = ls.getItem(k); " \
            "return items; ")

    def keys(self) :
        return self.driver.execute_script( \
            "var ls = window.localStorage, keys = []; " \
            "for (var i = 0; i < ls.length; ++i) " \
            "  keys[i] = ls.key(i); " \
            "return keys; ")

    def get(self, key):
        return self.driver.execute_script("return window.localStorage.getItem(arguments[0]);", key)

    def set(self, key, value):
        self.driver.execute_script("window.localStorage.setItem(arguments[0], arguments[1]);", key, value)

    def has(self, key):
        return key in self.keys()

    def remove(self, key):
        self.driver.execute_script("window.localStorage.removeItem(arguments[0]);", key)

    def clear(self):
        self.driver.execute_script("window.localStorage.clear();")

    def __getitem__(self, key) :
        value = self.get(key)
        if value is None :
          raise KeyError(key)
        return value

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.set(key, value)

    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key in self.keys()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.items().__iter__()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.items().__str__()
```

I'm positive that the local storage isn't the problem, i'm able to write / read from what i tried with some js.

My current problem is that when i press the load button and send the post my page crash with the following error :

```
Message: unknown error : unhandled inspector error:{"Code":"-32000", "message","Cannot navigate to invalid URL"}
```

if i copy paste the url that seem to be invalid for him it load without problems, so i'm not really sure what is making the url invalid for him ?

Comment: `url='XXX.X.X.XX:XXXX/XXXXXXX/XXXXXXX'
        driver.get(url)`
Is this the line from where you get the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say your url is valid and you are getting an invalid URL message try this:
Try storing the url into [String literals](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) (marked by r')

```
url = r'url_path_goes_here'
```